# Can regex select and ignore matches at the same time?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression 3 to detect phones in a large text and then replaced by "(phone)" for privacy reasons.

```
var phoneNumber = /\(?(?:[0-9]{2,4})\)?[- . ]{0,}?(?:[0-9]{2,4})[- . ]{0,}?(?:[0-9]{2,4})/gim;

var separatePhone = /(\d\s){8,}\d/gim;

var textPhone = /((one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero|\d)\s){8,}(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|zero|\d)/gim;
```

Then I check if my text match with each one.

Examples:

`I need 100000€ call me at 123456789 to talk about it.`

`Hi, can you buy this item (link) for $500.000? call me on +01123456789`

`Hi, can you buy this item (link) for £100000000? call me at 100000000`

The problem in this text is the `100000€` is detected as phone.

I want to match the phones but not the numbers with €, $ or £ ($ and £ at the beginning of the number), I already have this `(?![\€\$\£]\(?(?:[0-9]{2,4}))`, also I already try:

```
(?![\€\$\£]\(?(?:[0-9]{2,4}))(?=\(?(?:[0-9]{2,4})\)?[- . ]{0,}?(?:[0-9]{2,4})[- . ]{0,}?(?:[0-9]{2,4}))
```

But it doesn't work.

I check this regex in https://regex101.com/r/PJbIm9/14

**Update:**

I'm gonna use this expression (the original one in the project) whit the solution marked, i check the regex as array.

```
/[^$€£0-9]((?:[0-9]{2,4})\)?[- . ]{0,}?(?:[0-9]{2,4})[- . ]{0,}?(?:[0-9]{2,4})+)/gim;
```

Comment: Please provide more examples.

Comment: Try an easiest way, check the last character : str.slice(-1) != $ ....

Comment: @Jan i add one more, also you can try with the same number like `500000 and $500000` 

Also @Shim-Sao i just want use regex

Comment: You can save your check in regex101 and share it here

Comment: But what if it says `I need 100000 Euro call me at 123456789 to talk about it.`? I don't think a regex is good in this case aside from *possibly* narrowing down *potential* messages with phone numbers. I think in this case you have to easy options - either replace everything that looks like a phone (something like  - `I need (redacted)€ call me at (redacted) to talk about it.`) or just flag the messages and have somebody else walk through and decide for each one.

Comment: @HerrSerker https://regex101.com/r/PJbIm9/14 you can see here

Comment: @vlaz i can't control that because the messages are writen by the users, that's why I use the expresion for phones like XXX-XXX-XXX, (XXX)XXXXXX etc...

Comment: @CristianCV Post this share link into your question, not only into the comments

Comment: @CristianCV my point is that I don't think a regex can solve this. And you probably need a very complex system that will analyse the message based on its content, rather than pattern matching to even be able to determine if `100000` is an amount or a phone number. If you try to match `100000 Euro` that could still be wrong if the full context is `Call 100000 Euro needed` or something where Euro doesn't relate to the number. You can probably make some guesses based on the number matched (100000 is unlikely to be a phone number) but you can't know for sure.

Comment: @vlaz one user make it, you can see the rigth answer

Comment: @CristianCV [it fails](https://regex101.com/r/gqwAJT/3) with exactly the input I told you about. So this *only* works some of the time - when it doesn't, you're exactly in the same place as when you started this question only the solution via regex is VASTLY more complex and would be virtually unmaintainable.

Comment: @CristianCV Oh, in addition, the regex is now [completely borked](https://regex101.com/r/gqwAJT/5) when it comes to recognising actual phone numbers.

Comment: You are rigth @vlaz but that's why i gonna use the original regex for phones and also the new one, but the "euro" and thigs like that is gonna be hard/impossible to check

Comment: @CristianCV my point exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something simple like that ?

```
[^$€£0-9]([\d]+)[\s|.]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gqwAJT/2).

Comment: Works for € but not for $ or £, because they are before the number, gonna add more examples.

Comment: @CristianCV : I have edited my answer according to your needs

Comment: Paste it back into your answer?

Comment: This [doesn't really catch phone numbers any more](https://regex101.com/r/gqwAJT/7). It also would catch `100000 Euro` as being the phone number `100000`. Not to mention stuff like dates would also be flagged incorrectly as phone numbers and ANY other numbers

Comment: Check the Update of the post

Comment: And what about "dollars"? "USD" "pounds? "british pounds"? "GBP"? "cash"? "dosh"? "bling"? You can see how the complexity is going to explode and we're not even talking about complex cases yet - what about a message that contains "100000 to be paid on delivery". And how do you even deal with dates in this case - "2018" is still considered a phone number. Any number is considered a phone number unless excluded and there is no pattern matching way to determine conclusively if it is or not.

Comment: @vlaz yes of course you’re right! A perfect matching regex seems impossible in this case

Comment: @ElNino yes. Unfortunately, the question doesn't lend itself to one. At best, you can narrow down the potential phone numbers and then process them separately. Or maybe process the messages that *potentially* contain a phone number. Honestly, my best suggestion here is to find all messages that *might* contain a phone number and give them to a human to check and redact as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you could use the following mechanism:

```
(?: everything you do not want) | (important stuff)
```

Then check programatically if the group 1 has been set, e.g. for your examples given:

```
(?:\$[\d.]+|\d+€)|(\d+)
```

If you encounter other currencies, change the left branch in the non-capturing group and add alternations as needed. See [**your modified demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/PJbIm9/15).

---

In `JavaScript` that would be

```js
let data = `I need 100000€ call me at 123456789 to talk about it.

Hi, can you buy this item (link) for $500.000? call me on +01123456789`;

let rx = /(?:\$[\d.]+|\d+€)|(\d+)/g;
match = rx.exec(data);
while (match != null) {
    if (typeof(match[1]) != 'undefined')
        console.log(match[1]);
    match = rx.exec(data);
}
```

Comment: But in that demo is selected the 2 options, the phone and the amount of money, i just want to get selected the phones.

Comment: @CristianCV: I know, see the JS fiddle in the updated post. You need to make use of the groups here.

Comment: Already one user gave me the correct answer, thank you anyway